# Three points $a, b, c$ such that $\sqrt{x^2 - 2xy^4 + y^6, y^3 - y)} = I(a) \cap I(b) \cap I(c)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a problem I stumbled across in the notes for a class at Stanford. The hint is to interpret both sides geometrically, but I'm not really sure how to do so.

The right side is the intersection of three ideals, and we know that $I(p = (a_1, \dots, a_n)) = (x_1 - a_1, \dots, x_n - a_n)$, so we should interpret the right side as just those three points, $a, b, c$ (right?). But I'm more confused about how to interpret the left side. Any ideas?

Comment: you're supposed to find the solutions of $x^2-2xy^4+y^6=0,y^3-y=0$.

Comment: The left hand side is the [radical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_ideal) of the ideal generated by $x^2 - 2xy^4 + y^6$ and $y^3 - y$.

Comment: Sure, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to visualize the radical of the ideal. Or is this not what the hint means?

Comment: look up (if you don't know it) Hilbert's Nullstellensatz

Comment: I got it, thanks.